# Trying to get property of non-object when trying to print the collection laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make collection in laravel and trying to print it in view but this is showing me error

> Trying to get property of non-object

anyone tell me where I am wrong.

```
$seo = Collection::make([
    "meta_title" => "Eco Elegant - Frp Dustbins & Planters Manufacturers in India",
    "meta_desc" => "Eco Elegant is the leading manufacturer and designers of stainless steel/ (Fiber Reinforced Plastic) FRP planters and dustbins for places with diverse usage needs.",
    "meta_keyword" => "Eco Elegant, Frp Dustbins, Frp Planters, Stainless Steel Dustbins, Stainless Steel Planter, Dustbins and Planter Suppliers, Exporters in India"
]);

@if($seo->count() > 0)
    @foreach($seo as $seo1)
    <title>{{ $seo1->meta_title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $seo1->meta_desc }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ $seo1->meta_keyword }}">
    @endforeach
@else               
    <title>Eco Elegant</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the array index like

```
$seo1['meta_title']
```

Instead of

```
$seo1->meta_title
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a single array in the collection and not a collection of arrays or objects, you don't need to iterate over it.

So, remove the `foreach()` part and use:

```
$seo->meta_title
```

Instead of:

```
$seo1->meta_title
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems only one item in you collection as per your question So remove the foreach and try once

```
 @if($seo->count()>0)
    <title>{{$seo->meta_title}}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{$seo->meta_desc}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{$seo->meta_keyword}}">
@else               
    <title>Eco Elegant</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
@endif
```